# como poner la informacion de mi pagina sobre imagen?

Tags: html

Inicio

```
<img src="img/programacion.jpg">

<form action="Formulario_submit" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <center>

    <h1>Super Mundo Web</h1>

    <p>"Si puedes imaginar se puede programar"</p>
    <p>Somo una empresa comprometida con un unico objetivo
    satisfacer sus necesidades tenemos la suficiente experiencia para
    cumplir sus objetivos.</p>


    <br><label>Direccion : Calle 2c # 34B - 44</label></br>
    <br><label>Telefono : 7224567</label></br>
    <br>Email : mundoWeb@gmail.com</br>
    <br><a href="Servicios.php">Servicios</a></br>

    </center>
</form>
```

Comment: toda la información de tu formulario o cual información?

Comment: por solo es informacion basica no hay formulario

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta, ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente? ¿Y qué has intentado? Por otra parte tu código no es del todo correcto,¿por qué hay una etiqueta `form` si no es un formulario? Y la etiqueta `center` está desaprobada desde HTML4

Answer (score 2):

Con el atributo `title`:

```
  <img src="img/programacion.jpg" title="Hola Mundo!">
```

Comment: voy a mirar compañero

Comment: con title es para cuando pases encima el cursor pero luego de eso el texto no se ve mas

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo lo que buscas hacer es que la información en texto que decidas se ponga encima de una imagen; necesitas:

1. el elemento que va a quedar debajo es decir la imagen tenga position fixed
2. el elemento que va a quedar encima, el texto necesita un position relative

Mira este ejemplo

```
<style>
  img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
  #datos{
    position: relative;
  }
</style>
<img src="https://lasimagenesdegoku.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/12-1.png">


<div id="datos">
      <br><label>Direccion : Calle 2c # 34B - 44</label></br>
    <br><label>Telefono : 7224567</label></br>
    <br>Email : mundoWeb@gmail.com</br>
    <br><a href="Servicios.php">Servicios</a></br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres poner una imagen de fondo a tu página puedes hacerlo mediante `background-image: url('ruta/a/tu/imagen')`, la etiqueta [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) está deprecada, es mejor utilizar css para centrar el contenido, y por último la tag [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/br) no tiene etiqueta de cierre puedes ponerla como `<br>` o `<br />` para documentos XHTML pero no `<br></br>`

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/15/11/15/wintry-2068298_1280.jpg');
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Super Mundo Web</h1>

<p>"Si puedes imaginar se puede programar"</p>
<p>Somo una empresa comprometida con un unico objetivo satisfacer sus necesidades tenemos la suficiente experiencia para cumplir sus objetivos.</p>


<p>Direccion : Calle 2c # 34B - 44</p>
<p>Telefono : 7224567</p> 
<p>Email : mundoWeb@gmail.com</p>
<a href="Servicios.php">Servicios</a>
```